# Is it good practice to document thrown exceptions for interfaces?

Tags: c#, interface

As the title says: is it good practice to document thrown exceptions for interfaces? Does a generally agreed-upon best practice even exist? I feel it's an implementation detail that should not be included in the interface in any way, but at the same time I feel it's valuable information the user of the interface should have.

Whether comments like this are a good practice is a topic for another discussion, so to limit the scope of this question, let's assume that we've agreed that documenting code with comments like this is a good practice. Here with 'comments like this' I mean comments you can generate stuff from, i.e. documentation or metadata, and not just 'normal' comments. Examples include XML documentation, Javadoc, and Doxygen.

Now, which of these C# examples is the better practice, if any best practice can even be agreed upon?

Interface without exception documentation:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    /// <summary>
    /// Does something.
    /// </summary>
    void DoSomething();
}
```

Interface with exception documentation:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    /// <summary>
    /// Does something.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.Exception">Something went wrong.</exception>
    void DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: First of all, only use comments when necessary. I'd even question the need for the "Does something." comment. That aside, I may implement `IMyInterface` with a `DoSomething()` that catches `Exception`, which means your description is now wrong. The purpose of an interface is a contract. That contract cannot enforce exception throwing, so shouldn't be there.

Comment: @DavidArno There are so many things wrong with your comment. 1) using `///` does not create a normal comment, it creates metadata you can build documentation on. 2) It is perfectly acceptable to have possible known exceptions be part of the contract. 3) "Does something." is just example text for this snippet.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, your comment neatly highlights why I voted to close this question as "primarily opinion-based". You think I'm wrong; I think you are wrong. That doesn't make for good content on SO...

Comment: @DavidArno - The `exception` element documents which exceptions could be thrown from a method, so swallowing all exceptions wouldn't necessarily be a violation. However if an interface did describe the situations when an exception should be thrown and your implementation failed to do so then your code would be wrong. The C# type system is not powerful enough to enforce all required properties of methods so sometimes documentation (and code contracts) are required.

Comment: This question comes off as primarily opinion based. I'd recommend rewording it to ask if there's a recommended way from Microsoft, either in some standards document or by example in the source code for .NET itself.

Comment: @Lee, no my code would be doing precisely what I wanted it to do. If it were wrong, then it would cause a unit test to fail. If a unit test exists to ensure my code throws a required exception, then the interface doesn't need clogging up with noise. Either way, exception claims have no place in interface definitions.

Comment: @DavidArno - If you're implementing an interface you don't get to do whatever you want - failing to abide by the contract is an LSP violation. Thrown exceptions are part of the behaviour of a method and therefore can be mentioned in the method contract. Unit tests are not contracts either.

Comment: @Lee, random comments in an interface do not constitute a LSP need. Throw a `NotImplementedException` and LSP is broken; fail to throw an exception mentioned in a comment and Mrs Listov won't give a damn.

Comment: I agree with David Arno on this one. Documenting exceptions in an interface is wrong because it is a contract you can not enforce and can therefore be misleading.

Comment: I added some clarification about my original intent, but I believe it doesn't change the question from being primarily opinion-based. However, I also believe I should not edit it further to be less opinion-based because even knowing that a question is primarily opinion-based can be helpful to people (as it would have been to me).

Answer (score 16):

Interfaces are contracts, if part of that contract includes a situation that a exception is thrown you should definitely include it in your documentation. You can see examples of exceptions documented in interfaces all over the .NET framework, for example [`IEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset(v=vs.110).aspx) has quite a few. (Text retreived by right clicking on a declaration of `IEnumerator` and navigating to "metadata view")

```
  public interface IEnumerator
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Advances the enumerator to the next element of the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the enumerator was successfully advanced to the next element; false if the enumerator has passed the end of the collection.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The collection was modified after the enumerator was created. </exception><filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    bool MoveNext();
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the enumerator to its initial position, which is before the first element in the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The collection was modified after the enumerator was created. </exception><filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    void Reset();
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current element in the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// The current element in the collection.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    object Current { get; }
  }
```

Comment: I have searched for examples but didn't found any +1

Comment: Perfect example of how **not** to write an interface. You have to wade through pointless crap like "Gets the current element in the collection.", "The current element in the collection." to get to the actual content `object Current { get; }`. -1 for in any way implying this is good practice.

Comment: @DavidArno: why is it pointless crap to see in intellisense that `Current` returns the "current element in the collection" or that `MoveNext` throws an exception if "the collection was modified after the enumerator was created" when you are going to use this property? That are extremely valuable inforamtions.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, because it's called "Current", therefore it is ever-so-slightly obvious that it'll return the current element. If the comment is needed, then the name is bad, so maybe it should  have been called `CurrentElement`. If you need to comment code to explain it, then fix the code so it's more readable and obvious instead.

Comment: @DavidArno: so you think that it's best practice to omit documentation if a method/property name  is meaningful?

Comment: @DavidArno You are ever-so-slighlty wrong....the point being that the documentation is at least making clear some not so obvious information: in this case being that `Current` is a read only property, which is kind of handy information to pop up in intellisense when you are scanning a class you haven't used much.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, absolutely.

Comment: @InBetween the `{ get; }` bit is a bit of a big clue as to it's readonly-ness and, unlike the comment, is guaranteed to be valid info.

Comment: "Best practice" can be expressed as "what is going to help others understand my code as it's highly likely someone else will need to build off it." Documentation clearly provides a better atmosphere for coding for others. While `Current` may be obvious to you, it may not be obvious to others, and it's far more time-savvy to hover over a property or method than it is to "Go to Definition." Just my opinion though.

Comment: @DavidArno Huh? Are you being dense on purpose? What part of *intellisense* did you fail to understand? Those comments are not meant to be anything even similar to normal code commentaries (`// ...`), they are simply the standard way of enabling intellisense to understand and show meaningful information about any given type and its members. A bit of a clue: `{ get; } ` is not visible using *intellisense*. Oh and its also how the MSDN documentation is built too.

Comment: @DavidArno: then MSDN should be rewritten and all classes and methods should delete documentation when it's already meaningful.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I agree.

Comment: @DrewKennedy, and what is going to best help others understand my code is for me to write clear, easy-to-read code; not for me to hide my bad code behind reams of comments.

Comment: @InBetween, anyone resorting to name calling has lost the argument automatically.

Comment: @DavidArno I prefer qualifying some attitudes and comments outright more than using pointless petty condescending arguments of the type "*the `{ get; }` bit is a bit of a big clue*" as if you were, oh so much smarter than the rest of us... To each his own I guess. Oh, and there was no argument to win or lose to begin with, your position on the matter at hand is, to be honest, ludicrous.

Comment: @InBetween, to quote Uncle Bob, "The proper use of comments is to compensate for our failure to express yourself in code. Note that I used the word failure. I meant it. Comments are always failures." Rather than finding my position ludicrous and accusing me of being dense, please take the time to ready up on modern ideas around clean code and software craftsmanship. You'll be amazed just how non-isolated my views are if you do. You never know, you may even learn new ideas and modernise your own views too.

Comment: @DavidArno And there you go again, we are not discussing about code commenting. Why do you keep insisting on this subject that has very little to do with the example posted in the answer? We are discussing about framework documentation over which the MSDN reference library and VS's intellisense are built which is an altogether different matter. And believe me, in that aspect you'd be surprised how very isolated you are.

Comment: @InBetween, that might explain things. I've no particular views on MSDN docs, beyond the way they are generated (by polluting code with vast amounts of very noisy comments), thus my original comment to the OP that even the "Does something" comment was questionable as I can see that by the fact it's called `DoSomething`.

Comment: @DavidArno Yes, I agree its noisy and ugly; thankfully you can collapse them in most editors wich mitigates the issue somewhat. But I really think the documentation generated is useful and sometimes even necessary even though it is true that in some cases it might be somewhat obvious and of little or no use but then I do think consistency is also a factor to keep in mind.

Comment: I would not use `IEnumerator` or any .NET interface as an example as to why exceptions should be documented in an interface; such a vast framework has special considerations that normal day to day code does not. I sincerely think, that on a general basis,  its the wrong thing to do; you have no control whatsoever on who might implement your interface (unless its `internal` in which case the documentation might even be unnecessary) and if he'll abide by your *suggested* (not enforced) exceptions. I guess MS had good reasons to do it this way but it doesn't necessarily mean its right.

Comment: @InBetween: I would consider `IEnumerator<T>` as an example of an interface whose *failure* to adequately document exceptions creates a certain level of unresolvable semantic ickiness.  Many kinds of problems can occur while enumerating something; some are sufficiently severe that shutting down the program ASAP may be appropriate; others imply that the consumer should be aware that enumeration ended abnormally, but that if a client can deal with that there is no other problem.  I would posit that `IEnumerator<T>` really should have documented that it will throw a particular exception...

Comment: ...in the latter scenario (e.g. `CleanEnumerationFailureError`) with an `InnerException` describing the underlying problem.  Otherwise there's no way for client code to know what problems require handling beyond reporting that enumeration ended rudely.

Comment: @supercat true, and I agree that how and what exceptions are thrown by an enumerator could have been better thought out.  And like I said before, in a vast framework like .NET, documenting exceptions in an interface seems to be the reasoable thing to do: after all, 99.9% of the `IEnumerator`s you use are not user implemented so the point of not meeting the suggested exception contract is mute, and the risk of encountering bad behaved user implemented enumerators is low anyhow. But on a much smaller scale, I would tend to avoid making promises I can't really keep.

Comment: @InBetween: The "promise" implied by specifying `CleanEnumerationFailureException` is that an implementation should refrain from throwing exceptions besides those documented unless, in its "judgment", a situation exists which needs to be handled in some fashion beyond reporting "The collection could not be fully enumerated", and callers should handle `CleanEnumerationFailureException` if they judge that they can function usefully despite a failure to fully enumerate the collection.  The issue isn't just with user enumerators; I think there are enumerators...

Comment: ...in the framework for things like reading lines of text from a file, are there not?  What should such an enumerator do if it gets a disk error?

Comment: @supercat Evidently throw some, desirably, general type exception with more specific information of what really went wrong in the inner exception. I agree with you, I'm not arguing that point. I'm arguing about wether it should be documented the same way as `int.Parse` is, for example. The latter is enforced, the former is not. Maybe in a perfect versión of C#, it would have been interesting making exceptions part of the method's signature: `public Foo Bar() throws ArgumentException, InvalidOperationException` and have the compiler enforce it statically (and all related documentation).

Answer (score 4):

An interface only defines the contract of the operations to be done not how they are implemented. Consider the following example:

```
void Sort(SortOrder order);
```

You could be tempted to add a `throws ArgumentNullException if order is null` comment but what happens if the implementor of the interface decides that receiving a null on the `SortOrder` means that it should use a default `SortOrder`? (wrong decision but a possible one). This should be a valid decision for the one implementing the interface, and if it is not an option to decide things like this then you should be offering an abstract base class that throws the exception instead of an interface.

Adding exceptions to the interfaces is like making interfaces inherit from the IDisposable interface. These things are implementation details that shouldn't slip into the interface definition.

Comment: It largely depends. There are good example when it makes sense to include possible exceptions in the interface as Scott has shown. Here is another: `IList<string> list = new string[]{"foo"};
            list.Add("bah");`. If you hover over `Add` you are informed that this method might throw  a `NotSupportedException` if the underlying collection is read-only or fixed size (which is true in this case). That's also [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.add(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, throwing a `NotSupportedException` would be failing to fulfil the contract of the interface as it's probably the most obvious example of a LSP violation. You appear to both want interfaces to use comments to impose contracts on class and use comments to allow classes to avoid those contracts. Such abuses of comments is smeller than a class full of gotos.

Comment: I agree, a NotSupportedException looks like a shortcut to avoid creating right interfaces like IReadOnlyList.

Comment: @DavidArno, I think we are missing one thing: the `IList` interface is not all about one single method `Add()`, but it also contains `IsReadOnly` property, so not documenting the `NotSupportedException` might be a problem. I agree, it means comments = contracts, but why not, if its meaningful and useful for the developers who will implement the interface in their own classes? Even the very name of the method is some kind of a contract. For example, you can't implement the `Add(item)` method to actually **remove** the item